# More freehub removal problems.

Tags: wheels, hub

So helpful folks here helped me get the cog and lockring off, and now I'm stuck with this. I looked on Park's website again for "removal of freewheel" help, but mine didn't fit with any of the methods. No hex wrenches, screws, bolts or anything. The ratcheting mechanism just seems sort of...on it.

There's two notches (picture below), screams "two-pronged tool" but I'm starting to think this wheel simply cant be converted to a fixed wheel. New rear wheel perhaps?

[image]

Comment: Try using a putty knife or something on those two notches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the notches are about 25 mm apart, [this](http://www.parktool.com/product/freewheel-remover-FR-2) may be your baby:

[image]

On the Park Tool website there are two very informative documents on [freewheel removal](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/cassette-and-freewheel-removal), and [destructive freewheel removal](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freewheel-destructive-removal), which should answer all your questions.

Comment: Man, how did I miss this...?

Answer (score 3):

There's a special tool that matches those notches so you can dismantle the whole thing.

However, yeah, you'd be better off with a new rear hub. You can reuse the rim, if you get a hub with the same number of holes, but you'll need new spokes.

You're going to need to know the spacing of the rear dropouts on your frame and find a track hub that matches that.

For mountain bikes this is usually 135mm, 130mm for road bikes, and 120mm for track bikes.

Answer (score 2):

The two notches are to remove the bearing race and dismantle the freehub body often resulting in tiny bearings going everywhere and there a nightmare to re-assemble. If you want to remove the freehub body intact you need to use a 12mm Allan key from the opposite side of the hub.