# Removing Old Freehub Body

Tags: freewheel

I saw [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/14000/more-freehub-removal-problems).  However, looking at a old 7 speed freehub body, it looks like it takes a [special spline wrench (TL-FH10)](http://sheldonbrown.com/k7.html).  It looks very similar to the fixing bolt [here](http://sheldonbrown.com/images/freebod.gif).  Or do I need some other wrench to remove it using the notch?  I also did see [this](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freewheel-destructive-removal).

Do I need this special tool to remove this freehub body or am I totally off?  Is there some other way to remove it without destroying it?

**UPDATE**: The freehub body does not have notches on it.  I will post a picture of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a 10mm allen wrench was needed.  Looking at the head for the bolt, it looks special, but its not, so I was deceived.  Probably not a traditional bolt head, as the axle must fit through it.